# hibernate @Formula with CAST

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

The following snippet does work:

```
@Formula("CAST (SELECT AVG(p.\"date\") FROM prediction p) AS \"datetime\"")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date avgDate;
```

It results in a query (excerpt) containing:

```
SELECT proc0_.ID AS ID1_10_0_,
...
   proc0_.CAST
(SELECT AVG(p."date")
FROM prediction p) AS "datetime" AS formula0_0_,
...
```

And hibernate complains about:

```
... right syntax to use near 'SELECT AVG(p."date") FROM prediction p) AS "datetime" as formula0_0_'
```

Using `@Formula("SELECT CAST (AVG(p.\"date\") AS \"datetime\") FROM prediction p")` doesnt work either, with a similar error

From my understanding, sql breaks down, because hibernate somehow intepretes `CAST(` to be a field, because it preprends `proc0_` to it.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? (Maybe `@Formula` is not the right approach here?)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space after the `CAST` and you are fine:

```
@Formula("CAST(SELECT AVG(p.\"date\") FROM prediction p) AS \"datetime\"")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date avgDate;
```

Hibernates parser for `@Formula` is quite limited.

I'm missing any constraint in your expression - the current formula would return the same `avgDate` for every entity. But I guess that you have stripped that from your question to keep it simple...